# Issue with trying to Blur an image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

I am attempting to implement the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJIXTm_MsbY

I create the Blur class as instructed:

```
public class BlurBuilder {

    private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.1f;
    private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 5.5f;

    public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {

        int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);

        ScriptIntrinsicBlur scriptIntrinsicBlur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);

        scriptIntrinsicBlur.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        scriptIntrinsicBlur.setInput(tmpIn);
        scriptIntrinsicBlur.forEach(tmpOut);

        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;

    }

}
```

Then I am attempting to blur an image in my Adapter view as such which uses the inflater to display a list of images:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Games game = gameList.get(position);


    Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.forty);
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(this, originalBitmap);


}
```

The first issue is that the `getResources()` function is throwing an error

as is the `this` in the `BlurBuilder.blur` function.

I am not entirely sure how to get that resolved, does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the `Context` in recycler adapter directly. Get it by a `View` object. In your case either you pass the context through the constructor from an activity like:-

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity(){
 Context mContext;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mContext = this;

        adapter = new HomeAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
    }
}
```

Or you can try accessing directly from the onBindViewHolder Like :-

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Games game = gameList.get(position);

    Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(holder.itemView.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.forty);
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur(holder.itemView.getContext(), originalBitmap);

}
```